# What is the role of parentheses in XPath 1.0?

Tags: google-chrome, xpath, xpath-1.0

In Chrome DevTools > Elements, when I search for `//tr/td/span` I find an element (because such an element exists on my page).

When I search for `(//tr)/td/span` or `(//tr/td)/span` I also find this element.

But neither `//tr(/td)/span` nor `//tr/(td)/span` nor `//tr/(td/)span` find anything.

What is the meaning of these parentheses in XPath?

Answer (score 3):

Parenthesis in XPath are used as they are in other programming languages:

1. **Function argument grouping:** e.g: `//tr/td[contains(.,"e")]`
2. **Evaluation precedence indication:** e.g: normal arithmetic expression grouping as well as *leading* path grouping (trace [`LocationPath`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#NT-LocationPath) through to [`PrimaryExpr`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#NT-PrimaryExpr) in the XPath grammar) as in `(//td)[1]` to find the first `td` in the document as opposed to `//td[1]` which finds the `td` elements that are the first child of their respective parent elements.

They're also used in

1. **node tests**: e.g: `node()`, `element()`, ...
2. **processing instructions:** e.g: `PageBreak()`.

Your examples that do not find anything (e.g: `//tr(/td)/span`, `//tr/(td)/span`<sup>1</sup>, etc) have parenthesis embedded within the path that do not follow in one of the above categories.  Such use of parenthesis are actually ***syntactically invalid*** and should have been reported as such rather than silently failing.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Note that this expression would actually be syntatically valid under XPath 2.0/3.0.  Thanks, @Andersson, for noticing.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that parenthesis mean something in your case, but it might be used to return required node/nodes set depending on passed index

For instance, HTML is like below:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>first</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>second</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
      <span>third</span>
    </td>
      <td>
      <span>fourth</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

- `(//tr)[1]/td` will return cells for first row only (`first`, `second`)
- `(//tr)[2]/td` - for second row (`third`, `fourth`)
- `(//tr/td)[1]` - first cell of first row (`first`). *Note that `//tr/td[1]` will returns each first cell of each row (`first`, `third`)*

  ...

Comment: Good examples (+1), but note that OP's cases that return nothing are actually not well-formed XPath expressions and should have been reported as such.

Comment: Yep, `//tr(/td)/span` and `//tr/(td/)span` are invalid expressions, while `//tr/(td)/span` syntax should be acceptable for XPath 2.0/3.0

Comment: Good point about `//tr/(td)/span` in XPath 2.0/3.0.  I'm going to make that clearer in my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Your third bullet point *seems* to be the answer, but it's not clear to me why this ambiguity can't happen later in the path (why the opening parentheses are only allowed at the beginning).

Comment: Don't bother with later XPath versions. I'm familiar with UnionSet and the like, my question is specifically about the implementation in Chrome, which seems to make no sense to me.

Comment: @AndreKR: Which part makes no sense to you:  That Chrome didn't report an error for a syntactically invalid XPath (I'd like to see a screenshot of that added to your question), or whether XPath 1.0 allows such syntax (it does not; see grammar notes in my answer), or why XPath 1.0 designers decided not to allow such syntax (it needed leading path parens for precedence changing reason mentioned in my answer)?

Comment: @kjhughes Chrome doesn't report any errors in the search box, because it doesn't know that it's supposed to be XPath (it can search other things, too). What I don't understand is why leading path needs parentheses but later subpaths don't. What is different in that situation?

Comment: @AndreKR: If you're not issuing `$x()` in the developer's console, where are you doing it?

Comment: The search box at the bottom of the Elements tab.

Comment: I do not see where you're entering your XPath, but if you're not getting syntax errors, you should enter `$x(xpath)` in the console instead.