# how to select 2nd set of <ol> list with xpath

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to scrape the `tips` sections of these exercises but a lot of the pages are different resulting in a blank field.

The only thing they all have in common is that the tips are always in the 2nd oldered list. The 1st ordered list is the instructions. 2nd ordered list are the tips.

Here are some of the xpath that I have tried:

`//ol` (this selects both ordered lists)

`//ol[2]` (this doesn't work at all for some reason)

`//h3[contains(text(),'​Exercise Tips:')]/following::ol` (some of the pages it didn't pick up tips section)

`//DIV[@class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/OL[2]` (again some of the pages it returned blank)

Link to the some of the exercises that the page are different:
https://www.muscleandstrength.com/exercises/one-arm-kettlebell-floor-press
https://www.muscleandstrength.com/exercises/overhead-tricep-extension.html

Answer (score 0):

I would try `//div[contains(@class, "exercise-tips")]//li/text()`.

Based on your example xpaths, you could use `//div[contains(@class, "exercise-tips")]//ol` if you truly want to select the `ol` element and not the text of the tips.

`//ol[2]` doesn't select any nodes because both `ol` nodes are the first `ol` child of their respective parents, not the second. `(//ol)[2]` does work, however. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52166328/5225301 for more details.